# How common is the use of Angular along with Laravel as a backend for web apps?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, web-applications

Both angular and laravel are great frameworks meant for slightly different purposes. Since they achieve to do similar things like -

1. They both focus on an MVC-inspired application structure, and each of them support a different directory structure by default
2. They both offer templating engines of their own, with conflicting syntax (which can be changed of course)
3. They both offer DOM iterators ( php foreach vs ng-repeat )
4. And many more similar conflicts

Since they are so similar in philosophy, isn't it redundant (and even conflicting sometimes) to develop a web app which uses both these frameworks?

Since each of them are so powerful in themselves, would it be a good idea to mix both? How common is the combined use of these in real world websites?

Am I better off using angular with basic PHP instead, if say, I was developing a medium scale web service (5000+ users)

What are some of the other backend+frontend framework combinations which are symbiotic and most frequently used?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can do similar things, but they don't *have* to.

Of course it doesn't make much sense to use the same feature of both of the frameworks. Meaning if you choose to use AngularJS for templating you don't need Laravel's views. But that's nothing you should worry about. If you don't use it, you don't use it. The fact that you don't use the entire functionality of a framework shouldn't have any bad impact on your application.

But note: **Be consistent**

Don't render one view with Laravel and use AngularJS for the other.

### Recommendation

I personally have made good experiences with Laravel as a RESTful API and AngularJS taking care of the rest. So AngularJS is doing all the frontend stuff and communicates with Laravel only via JSON.